# What onomatopeia is ばたりばたり?

Tags: words, onomatopoeia

In Miyazawa Kenji's 銀河鉄道の夜 I came across this:

```
たくさんの輪転器がばたりばたりとまわり、...
```

What is the meaning of ばたりばたり here? 輪転器 is a [rotary printing press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_printing_press), I believe.

[バタバタ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/what-does-%E3%83%90%E3%82%BF%E3%83%90%E3%82%BF-mean?rq=1) comes to mind, so maybe something close to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"***With a repetitive (and mechanical) flopping sound***" would be my own definition.

At least, that should capture the essence of the onomatopoeia in the given context.